# Find max time from string list

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find max time from a list of time formats, Its not exactly `TimeSpan` so parsing it won't help.
Please suggest a solution.

```
var duration = new List<string>() { "116:48:28", "110:36:28", "16:30:28"};
var maxts = duration.Max(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x));
```

Comment: What format is that? Is it a duration in hh:mm:ss?

Comment: Its not proper date format, Hour can go beyond 60, but minutes and seconds are normal.

Comment: @shijithmc I think you mean the hour can go beyond 24.

Comment: Yes, Its actual not time format, Its used to find duration between two dates in hours, minutes and second.Minutes and second is between 0 to 59.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this. it will work in case, that you don't have something such as "1:70:10"...

```
duration.Select(d=>d.Replace(":", string.Empty)).Select(int.Parse).OrderBy(s=>s)
```

Or,  to get tha value of maximal timestamp:

```
duration.Select(d => new {Text =d, Val = int.Parse(d.Replace(":", string.Empty))})
        .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Val)
        .First()
        .Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ`:

```
var sortedDuraion = duration
    .OrderByDescending((s) => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(':')[0]))
    .ThenByDescending((s) => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(':')[1]))
    .ThenByDescending((s) => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(':')[2]));

var max = sortedDuration.ElementAt(0);
```

Also you can parse this `string` to `int` (delete `":"`) and order as `int` values:

```
var sortedDuration = duration.OrderByDescending((s) => Convert.ToInt32(s.Replace(":", String.Empty)));

var max = sortedDuration.ElementAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var duration = new List<string>() { "116:48:28", "110:36:28", "16:30:28" };
List<TimeSpan> lst = new List<TimeSpan>();
foreach (var item in duration)
{
    string[] data=item.Split(new char[]{':'});
    lst.Add(new TimeSpan(int.Parse(data[0]),int.Parse(data[1]),int.Parse(data[2])));
}
var max = lst.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
internal static TimeSpan ParseSpecialTimespan(string toParse)
{
    string pattern = @"^(\d+):([0-5]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1})$";

    var match = Regex.Match(toParse, pattern);
    if (!match.Success) throw new ArgumentException(@"The provided string is not valid...");
    int hours = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].ToString());
    int minutes = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].ToString());
    int seconds = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].ToString());
    TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
    return t;
}
```

Here's how it's used:

```
var duration = new List<string>() { "116:48:28", "110:36:28", "16:30:28" };
string largestInput = "";
TimeSpan largestTimespan = new TimeSpan(0);

foreach (string d in duration)
{
    TimeSpan parse = ParseSpecialTimespan(d);

    if (parse > largestTimespan)
    {
        largestTimespan = parse;
        largestInput = d;
    }
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(@"Largest timespan is ""{0}"" from input ""{1}"".", largestTimespan.ToString(), largestInput);
```